# Imagem perfil Google no FireStorage do FireBase

Tags: android, firebase

Estou com dificuldades para o seguinte código:

```
StorageReference imagemRef = storageReference
        .child("imagens")
        .child("perfil")
        .child(Jogador.uid + ".jpeg");

UploadTask uploadTask = imagemRef.putFile(acct.getPhotoUrl());
```

Onde `acct` é `GoogleSignInAccount` que retorna a Uri da imagem do perfil google. 
Alguém sabe me dizer o que tem de errado? Já que "putFile"  aceita Uri como parâmetro.

Comment: O erro ocorre no imagemRef.putFile(acct.getPhotoUrl());

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

Comment: verifica se `acct.getPhotoUrl()` é uma uri válida e tenta usar o `putFile` passando um arquivo

Comment: Consigo carregar essa Uri em uma ImageView com o Picasso! Vou continuar procurando uma solução.

Comment: Então o problema está ou no retorno de `acct.getPhotoUrl()` ou o _"Já que `putFile` aceita Uri como parâmetro"_ não é bem assim, da uma olhada na documentação oficial, irá ajudar

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, vou verificar!